# Why is there more gap under logo on contact page?

Tags: css

[image]

[image]

If you see 2 images above, you will see that one has more gap under the logo. Both pages have the same styles I don't understand why is there more gap on 1 of them.

The page with correct gap under logo is at http://snapnsolve.com/index.html
And the page with more gap is http://snapnsolve.com/contactus.html

Can anyone point out the problem?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the id #topsochd has a height of 60px in your index page, but it has a height of 40px in contactus.html. Change it to 60px in contactus.html  also.
Hence in contactus.html:

```
#topsochd {
height: 60px;/*not 40px*/
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #FFF;
width: 100%;
z-index: 99999;
```

}

Adding to that the float property in top-left -logo is also interfering with the problem. remove the float property and instead put a position:absolute which will automatically float your logo to the left.

```
#top-left-logo {
position: absolute;
}
```